# How to open multiple modals from the multiple product tiles having the same DOM structure?

Tags: html, css, sass, bootstrap-4

I am using boostrap modal here that is customized upto some extent. I have the following HTML in a single product on the PLP of my site:

```
    <div class="modal size-variants fade pr-0" id="tumbler-size-modals" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Variants are loading..</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This modal is triggered from this `a` tag:

```
   <div class="more-sizes-link hide-mobile">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tumbler-size-modals">
            <isprint value="${Resource.msg('more.sizes.text.nonmobile', 'plp', null)}" />
        </a>
    </div>
```

This is the CSS for the same:

```
.modal-backdrop.show{
    opacity: 0;
}

.modal-open{
    overflow-y: visible;
}

.modal{
    position: absolute;
    top: unset;
    bottom: 23%;
    border: 1px solid $border-grey;
    background-color: $transparent-white;
}
```

Currently this modal pops up as expected for a single product tile on the PLP, but when I try to open the same modal from another tile while another modal is open, there is no action. What can I do to pop this modal up from multiple product tiles.

Here is the image that displays the modal successfully popped up for one product tile:

[image: Here is the image that displays the modal successfully popped up for one product tile]

This is the link that needs to clicked to open the modal successfully specifically for this product tile:

[image: This is the link that needs to clicked to open the modal successfully specifically for this product tile]

I want to open another modal from the marked link while another one is open. So, how can I achieve the same?

Is there anything specific that I need to keep in mind in order to achieve this?

*I haven't added ISML in the tags although I am trying this using Demandware ISML templates, but that is irrelevant to the question that I have here.*

Comment: So every product that has the modal has the same modal id of `tumbler-size-modals'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my comment, you will want to make sure the ID is unique. I placed an example variable in the ID but you will want to make sure it works for your system.

```
    <div class="modal size-variants fade pr-0" id="tumbler-size-modals-${product_id}" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Variants are loading..</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


   <div class="more-sizes-link hide-mobile">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tumbler-size-modals-${product_id}">
            <isprint value="${Resource.msg('more.sizes.text.nonmobile', 'plp', null)}" />
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: cool, thanks, this might totally solve my issue, let check, if there is some issue still remaining after this, I will update my question here. Otherwise, this might be the type of solution that I have been looking for.

Comment: seems like `data-target="#tumbler-size-modals-${product_id}"` cant be done, as `#` and `$` cannot be used together in an ISML template, what can I do in this case?

Comment: I have found a solution to this, I have passed the hash value in resource messages and then appended the product ID to it, so that the ID is always unique. Your solution gave me that idea and with a bit of scratching my head, I have achieved that. So thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

The ID  and the according data-target has to be unique add product id or something unique to  `id="tumbler-size-modals"`

Comment: okay cool, thanks, now I think I get where my solution wrong. This might help me get what I need.

Comment: in general ID's have to be unique. If you want to do something to many elements you should use classes.

Comment: But this is bootatrap modal, cant really use custom js just to open a modal, if bootstrap is already integrated with my project